# Best way to insert upto 1 million documents into mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i need to upload an excel file with around 1 million records into mongodb. Can anyone please help with the best way insert 1 millon documents into mongodb.

Comment: Save it as csv and feed it to `mongoimport`. Should be the fastest way (both in terms of import speed and developer productivity (no code needed!))

Comment: It should be possible to convert your excel into a CSV, then use mongoimport to load them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using nodejs I suggest(I think you already use this) you to use mongoose as ODM as your data mapper for mongoDb.

Now in mongoose you have a method called

```
Model.insertMany(arrayOfObjects,callback);
```

so using this you can achieve what you are looking for. Besides mongoose handles this very good so the execution time is very low when it comes to this method other than other methods mongoose provides

Comment: It might be problematic to simultaneously have million documents in memory.

Comment: @THEWOLF thank for reply,  i am currently using insertMany function itself, but it is failing around 100k record. Sometimes it is throwing 16MB document limit exceed or http timeout.

Comment: well in that case you will have to convert excel to csv and import using mongo Import

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never use Mongoose node library for such things,

[see performance difference](https://medium.com/@bugwheels94/performance-difference-in-mongoose-vs-mongodb-60be831c69ad)

Mongoose are super slow with comparison to native MongoDB library.

Also, make sure you don't have any indexes in your table since that might slow 
down insert process.

disable Journal in your MongoDB config, and use `insertMany` and make sure to set `writeConcern` to 0 so, we disable acknowledge response, and that will speed up the process.

Finally make sure to get a good SSD hard disk, and you're good to go.